# Errors when saving hasMany with parent using Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have some nested Ember Data models `week->hasMany('workout')->hasMany('exercises')`

In my app I need to create an entire new week.  I accomplish this by

```
var newWeek = WT.PlanWeek.store.createRecord('planWeek', attributes );

// create a couple new workouts
newWorkout = WT.PlanWorkout.store.createRecord('planWorkout', attributes);
newWeek.get('workouts').pushObject(newWorkout);
// repeat...

// create exercises on the workouts the same way and push them on the the workout
newExercise = WT.PlanWeek.store.createRecord('planExercise', attributes);
newWorkout.get('exercises').pushObject(newExercise);

newWorkout.save();
```

I have a couple problems with this save.

1. I save the both the workout and the child exercises in the workout API call - when the call returns this appends a second set of exercises to the workout instead of replacing the existing exercises (even though I set `workout.exercises` to the newly persisted exercises in the serializer extractSingle).
2. When the server returns it doesn't update the workouts in the week with the new ids.  I end up with the new persisted workouts that correctly belongTo the week, but `week.get('workouts')` still points to the unpersisted workouts with no id.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Some additional info:  I overrode `didSaveRecord` and the record id is null, but if I try to set the id it says it is already set.

Comment: Also - #2 is fixed if I save the workout first, then add to the week afterwords, but this makes the UI appear really slow.  I would think that the ids would just be updated after the save.